# assuming IAM role multiple times using boto3 in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam, assume-role

I'm new to working with aws and I'm not sure if I'm wording it correctly but basically, I need to sso in an account -> assume a role in account A -> then assume a role in account B.
I am following this article (https://medium.com/geekculture/programming-aws-iam-using-aws-python-sdk-boto3-part-4-62f2f1c21584) on how to assume the role. After I assume the first role in account A, I get the "iam_client" (from the article), then I don't know how can I assume the second role from account B.

```
import boto3
```

from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

def lambda_handler(event, context):

```
sts_client = boto3.client('sts')

try:
    response = sts_client.assume_role(
        RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::<TRUSTING_ACCOUNT_ID>:role/<ROLE_NAME_IN_TRUSTING_ACCOUNT>',
        RoleSessionName='assume_role_session'
    )
except ClientError as error:
    print('Unexpected error occurred... could not assume role', error)
    return error

try:
    iam_client = boto3.client('iam',
                              aws_access_key_id=response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
                              aws_secret_access_key=response['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
                              aws_session_token=response['Credentials']['SessionToken']
                              )
except ClientError as error:
    print('Unexpected error occurred... could not create iam client on trusting account', error)
    return error
```

EDIT: my aws accounts are setup in a way that I can't assume the role in account B right after sso login. The trust relationship is setup in a way that it only allows a role in account A to assume it.

Comment: hi qabootar, would you mind sharing some sample code as well. it's unclear where you're stuck on and what help you need otherwise.

Comment: By getting a `boto3.client('sts'` in exactly the same way that it currently builds the `iam` client.

Comment: @HaleemurAli hi, I basically followed the article that I mentioned, (but ill edit the question and put the code there too) and in the end, I am left with iam_client. and basically, people are using this returned variable with one of the methods that boto3 provides, for example, response = iam_client.list_groups_for_user()
but I am looking to assume another role but I can't figure out how do I do it, I mean do I even have to use the "iam_client" that I end up with in the end?

Comment: @luk2302 when I do this process using the terminal I have to first sso -> assume role in account A and then assume role account in B, my aws accounts are setup in a way that I can't assume the role in account B right after sso login. The trust relationship is setup in a way that it only allows a role in account A to assume it. I hope that makes sense. 
now when it comes to using boto3, using python. I cant figure how do I achieve these steps sort of, sso -> assume role in account A -> assume role in account B.

Comment: @luk2302 maybe I need to do something like this `session = Session(iam_client)` and then `client = session.client('sts')` and then again do `client.assume_role(information about role to be assumed)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the **AWS Official Code Library** that contains this use case. When looking for an AWS code example, check this New AWS Doc.

[image]

As you can see, the code library shows this use case in different supported programming langanges. The topic is here:

[Create an IAM user and assume a role with AWS STS using an AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/iam_example_iam_Scenario_CreateUserAssumeRole_section.html)

You can assume roles by following the Python example.